# Directive on ready function should only execute once

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, document-ready

Hi Experts I have a directive 'my-table' in which there is a button for edit record.
Inside directive template (html file) I have a button

```
<a data-activates="editScreen" class="button-collapse">Edit
</a>
```

Inside JS file

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
    menuWidth: 450,
    edge: 'right', 
    closeOnClick: true 
});

})
```

I want to initialize sideNav on document ready function

Problem is this directive call in loop and every time directive called this code execute that will create problem. (So many Backdrop classes in view that will not let side nav close as expected)

I want this code to execute only once.

How can I solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just use a true directive, something like this :

```
angular.module('[moduleName]').directive('buttonCollapse', function(){
    return{
         restrict:'C',
         link:function(scope, element, attrs){
             $(element).sideNav({
               menuWidth: 450,
               edge: 'right', 
               closeOnClick: true 
             });
         }
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand. How can I use this. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: i edited because i forgot the `.module`before `.directive`. You were talking about a directive, so i made you one that match to your need. This will make all element having class "button-collapse" to be consider as a new angular directive and will be proceed as written in the link function. The link function is executed only at the creation of the element so no more problems of multiple execution.

Comment: Thanks for reply. very decent solution. But the only problem is side nav is not getting close on click outside as it was earlier.

Comment: is there any other attribute like "parent" ? For some of those components you have to define which DOM element is there parent in order to close when you click outside of the parent, and sometimes by default the parent is the <body>